# Oracle Enterprise Manager - Where do I find the error logs?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I'm not familiar with oracle management. The problem is when I try to connect to the enterprise manager through the Web browser I get this error:

[image]

In english: "Internal Error has occurred. Check the log file for details."

Where to find the log file to see what's the problem?

I'm using Windows 7 and Oracle 11gR2 EE.

Comment: Can you translate that error message accurately for us? Maybe best to change the language to English so we can see the exact, Googleable text.

Comment: Internal Error has occurred. Check the log file for details.

Answer (score 5):

ORACLE_HOME/HOSTNAME_SID/sysman/log

... is where I finally found them. I don't know if this is system dependent; this was on a linux box.